# How to successfully deploy my Vue app? (CLI3)

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vue-cli-3

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936588/how-to-deploy-vue-app) states that `npm run build` creates a `dist` folder (it does in my case) as well as an `index.html` file - it doesn't in my case.

Instead I have an `index.html` file inside my `dist` folder, and I upload this folder to my remote server, visiting that `index.html` in my browser displays a blank page with "Hello world" on top (no CSS, no JS).

I couldn't find anything addressing this issue in [the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines).

Am I missing something? Why is my app reduced to a mere "Hello world" page once deployed?

Comment: Check your console for errors (e.g., `404`s for missing files). Also verify you're actually looking at your Vue app by checking the source panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue-cli, to create dist folder you need to run npm run build.
Also , open your package.json and check your scripts objects. It will have various commands to run and you can chose the correct script to run.

```
"scripts": {
 "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
 "build": "vue-cli-service build",
 "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
},
```

For vue cli3, mostly you need to run npm run build.

Comment: Gosh I'm sorry, I wanted to write `build` not `serve`. I did run `npm run build`, not `npm run serve`. I updated my question.