# Vue js Development Code is Working fine but Production build Gives Blank white screen on Opening

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Developers Recently i am working on a vue js Website, and everything is working fine on Development but when i build the code using npm run build , the production build gets successfully build but when i try to open the index.html file inside dist directory the file gets opened in Browser but a Blank white page gets Displayed.

Comment: Can you share a piece of code with us? Maybe the relevant components?

Comment: is package.json file will work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your server, not open the file directly.
Because Vue builds files and connects JS and CSS like it would be on the server.
And now, when you are opening the file, it can't find JS/CSS.

Comment: It would be really great if you can please have a look at this question and provide some work-around? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72198087/7584240 Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to deploy your app? I think the following post can help you:
[How to deploy vue app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936588/how-to-deploy-vue-app)

Please check if you have a vue.config.js file and if the configuration is correct according to your project setup.