# What can be the next step after running npm build in vue app to deploy it on server?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to deploy vue app on server ,
i have run `npm run build` , after executing this it has created a

1. index.html file
2. Dist folder contains (build.js & build.map.js)

I am not sure what is the next step after this to get the app on server
Can anybody help on this ?

Comment: Serve it? Depends on the server you are using. Probably tutorials out there

Comment: What server are you going to deploy this app to? Apache, NGINX? Express?

Comment: Apache is the server , coz i am also running magento  over there

Answer (score 0):

For deployment please read the official docs from,

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines

It contains instructions specific to different deployment platforms

Comment: Sir this doc may contain some commands that are not necessary to deploy webpack standalone app on server.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear then.
Do you want to deploy your vue app on a server ? Then, the guidelines are given there.

If you have a preferred hosting platform eg: firebase, heroku, then, there are also guidlines given there.

Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thankyou for your response , earlier i've tried implementing this steps given in answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936588/how-to-deploy-vue-app

Comment: But that answer seems to be incomplete , that' why i had to ask question.

Comment: Yes, the answer is incomplete
It specifies `npm run build` command, which only bundles your source code for deployment and populates the dist folder. After this you have to actually deploy your dist folder.
The guidelines for deploying the generated dist folder is given in the official docs.
Fox example, if you want to deploy your app in github pages, follow this, https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages.
From sidebar you can chose from a number of different platforms.

Comment: Yes , let me take a look at that

Comment: Hello , i have not tried it yet , soon i am going to try & update for sure :)